# default namecheap "under construction" homepage and SEO

Tags: seo, construction, namecheap

I'm currently developping a site and I already purchased the domain name on namecheap.

I never asked google to index it but I just discovered that I already have a result typing site:mysite.com, because namecheap put a default webpage and google found it.

My problem is that I've been told that the beginning of a site on google was important because the google bot determined if the site was updating regularly to know if it had to come back often or not, the more often being of course the best. And here I missed the beginning.

- So what should I do ?
- Am I right worrying ?
- The indexed page is non-www. When my site will be ready, should I ask google to index the www one so google does as if he never indexed it ?
- Should I somehow ask google to un-index it and re-index it when it will be ready ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry. Google will not punish you for a default namecheap page.
It's better though to put up one page of your own with a message about what you will do with the domain name.

Comment: I agree. Google knows when new domains are registered and spider them immediately, within a day, and index them within a day. This should be a warning to folks to create a basic page before registering a new site, however, there is no harm in having a parked domain for a period. Do not worry about it. Create a quick and dirty page to begin your SEO imprint if you can and develop your site as you intended.